# Is there way to find Java memory leak using gdb

Tags: memory-leaks, gdb, java-7

I have Java7 application and it has Class loader leaks. I took heap dump on when out of memory occurs(using -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError) and analyzed using Eclipse MAT.

Apart from this Is there any way to find leak using gdb?

Comment: Hi there, you could use the VisualVM to monitor the object creation, and analyze which ones are being created and not garbage collected. Also you could use the jstat command to monitor the young and old generations of objects to try figuring out how they are going to old generations without being removed from the heap.

Comment: I have done this. But I actually wanted to know more about whether/how gdb helps to find memory leak ?